# Need help for making this .txt files TRUE

Tags: python, text, operating-system

Good day everyone, How can i make this thing make TRUE? I already have existed .txt files but the outcome always False.

```
ID = input("Enter the name of your .txt file: ") +".txt" +"'"
IDS = "'" + ID
file_exists = os.path.exists(IDS)
print(file_exists)
print(IDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `'` before and after the file name:

```py
ID = input("Enter the name of your .txt file: ") +".txt"
file_exists = os.path.exists(ID)
print(file_exists)
print(ID)
```

For example, if you had `foo.txt` and you put `foo` into your program, then your current code would look for a file named `'foo.txt'`, *not* `foo.txt`.

Comment: Dude, thank you thank you so much!!  I did rely on the 'Sample.txt'.. thank you once again, I finally understand now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#You may want to use str.strip() to get rid of unnecessary whitespaces
ID = input("Enter the name of your .txt file: ").strip() + ".txt"
file_exists = os.path.exists(ID)
print(f'{ID} exists') if file_exists else print(f'{ID} file does not exist')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes, you are adding single quotes to start and end of your string. Your code should look like this:

```
ID = input("Enter the name of your .txt file: ") +".txt" 
file_exists = os.path.exists(ID)
print(file_exists)
print(IDS)
```

Quotes in programming languages indicate what are strings, and they are omitted by the interpreter when you output it into a terminal (print)